# Javascript Variables Declaration

Tags: javascript, declaration

I am confused in how the variables are declared in javascript

consider this code

```
var a=5;
console.log(a);
var a=8;
console.log(a);
```

This returns

```
5
8
```

but shouldn't it return 8 twice?

Comment: No, why should it?

Comment: since all declarations are sent to the top during hosting then only one value of a should be existing

Comment: Only the `var a` part (the declaration) is hoisted, not the definition or initialization.

Comment: JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.

Comment: Yet another good dupe target find by @Juhana. :-)

Comment: Please do a search before posting questions.